# Amazon EC2 small instance not responding

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

My Amazon EC2 small instance stopped responding, I looked at the AWS console and CPU use had gone through the roof. I tried rebooting instance but it didn't respond. So I stopped it and started it again (twice).

Now says the CPU usage is fine (was triggering an alarm when breaching 90%) but still can't login via SSH and Apache is not working (my sites are down).

Anyone give me any idea how I can sort this out? I'm out of my depth a bit as unfamiliar with the ins and outs of EC2.

EDIT: console log http://pastebin.com/JWFeG7NU shows Apache, SSH, etc starting up fine but I can't access via SSH and no response to pinging website hosted on server.

Comment: I had a redmine instance running on there (ultra small instance).  When things got a bit busy, amazon would throttle my badly enough for my server not to respond.  I just had a wait a while until it settled.  The essentially "steal" back the over-usage CPU from you until the status quo has been restored.

Comment: Do you know if this would this apply to small instance, I knew they did that with micro instances which is why I upgraded to a small.

Comment: Not sure, but I expect so.  Essentially you are buying a "part" of a CPU, so the same rules should apply.

Comment: Right, so they cut off your shell access and everything aswell by just refusing any CPU power?  Looking at the CPU usage there is still some usage just way below previus level. Do you know if instance would just come online or do I have to keep rebooting it to get apache etc back up.

Comment: My instance just become unresponsive.  It may not be the case, but that was my experience.  I would rectify itself after some time (generally a few minutes).  Rather don't reboot - as that adds CPU cycles.  Just wait a few minutes and then investigate or throttle your application.

Comment: If you run `top` what's the percentage `steal` when it's unresponsive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have stop/started your instance and you were not using an elastic IP address, your instance IP has changed.

If you were using an elastic IP address, it would have become disassociated.

If you do have applications that are causing you to exceed the allocated CPU, other applications such as ssh, may become slow to respond or not respond at all within the timeout.

Comment: Thanks a million, I didn't notice that, things are back up.